# Github pages e rstudio

Tags: github, r, markdown

Estou usando o `Rstudio` para criar meus documentos no formato `.Rmd` e renderizo em `.md` com a seguinte função:

```
rmarkdown::render("2016-09-07-post1.Rmd",output_format = "md_document",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

O arquivo `.md` gerado é salvo na pasta `_posts`, faço o `commit` e o `push`, e então ao abrir o meu blog meu post é renderizado, porém acontece o seguinte:

- As imagens não aparecem;
- Os textos em Latex não são renderizados de forma correta.

Vocês podem visualizar isso em [fsbmat.github.io](https://fsbmat.github.io/2016-09-07-post1)

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esses problemas?

Comment: Já tentou usar o formato HTML no knitr (em vez de markdown)? Ele inclui as images "inline"

Comment: Oi @Marcelo de Andrade, já tentei sim, gero o html via knitr no Rstudio e coloco na pasta _post com o mesmo nome do arquivo .md, faço o commit e o push e na hora de visualizar no blog aparece os dois posts, porém com os mesmos problemas! Os dois encontram-se no blog para visualizar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o erro da imagem é bizarro, o motivo era a formatação da data no preâmbulo do arquivo, antes meu preâmbulo era:

`title: "Post1"
author: "Fernando de Souza Bastos"
date: 07 de setembro de 2016
layout: post
comments: true
output:
  html_document:
    variant: markdown_phpextra+backtick_code_blocks`

Mudei para:

`title: "Post1"
author: "Fernando de Souza Bastos"
date: "2016-09-07"
layout: post
comments: true
output:
  html_document:
    variant: markdown_phpextra+backtick_code_blocks`

E o gráfico renderizou!

Em relação ao latex, basta acrescentar as linhas de código abaixo no arquivo head.html que está na pasta _includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
      src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
```

Espero que ajude outros!